# rails: Link_to find-method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, find, link-to

How do I use link_to like a database filter in rails?

images --> belong_to: galleries --> Click on gallery --> Opens view of all images of the gallery (Not of all records in database!)

```
<%= link_to 'Images of Gallery', controller: "images" %>
```

This is working, but it shows me all available pictures in the database. I need to put something like the next snippet to the link_to:

```
@gallery = Image.find(params[:gallery_id])
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A `link_to` for an specific image? What do you mean by "like a database filter in rails"?... you can pass the object you are trying to open directly to the `link_to` like: `= link_to 'show view', @image`

Comment: If I click on the gallery link i want to see all the pictures, that belong to the gallery (specific ID). I dont want to see all the pictures that are in my database by clicking the link. The gallery overview was generated by an "each" iteration through the database.

Comment: It seems to me that you should be linking to the gallery show view. Then, in that view, you should loop through all the galleries images and show them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why both answers did't work. I got an error "Couldn't find without ID" error.

This solution did the job:

I called a before_action method in my controller:

```
before_action :set_gallery, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

in the set_gallery method I put this:

```
  def set_gallery
    @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    @images = @gallery.images
  end
```

Then I changed the link_to the the basic show action:

```
<%= link_to 'Preview', gallery %>
```

After that I changed the show.html.erb and added an image iteration:

```
  <% @images.each do |image| %>
  ... <%= image.img_url %> ...
  <% end %>
```

I will try to find out, why your suggested solutions didnt work. Cant explain it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you define

```
@gallery = Image.find(params[:gallery_id])
```

in action of your controller.
You can pass parameter in `link_to` method:

```
<%= link_to 'Images of Gallery', controller: "images", gallery_id: your_gallery_id %>

# or link should be map to show action instead of index action

<%= link_to 'Images of Gallery', controller: "images", action: "show", gallery_id: your_gallery_id %>
```

It allows you to access the `gallery_id` parameter in the controller and find the correct record.

Answer (score 0):

It's showing the images of all the galleries because your are not passing a `gallery_id` that the controller can use to filter the images, you are hiting the index action. So, just modify your link to show the images of that specific gallery:

```
<%= link_to 'Gallery', @gallery %> or just <%= link_to @gallery %>
```

And the controller show view should query for the images linked to that specific gallery

```
def show
  gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
  @images = gallery.images
end
```